# Executors or withPool construct

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a collection. For every item in the collection, I need to make a web service call and then update something in a cache.  I am doing this sequentially but it is too slow.  The items in the collection and their web service calls are independent from each other.  So no web service call interferes with any other.

So I want to make this happen in parallel.  I was going to use the

```
withGroup {
}
```

construct but is this only suited to working on data that is completely within the closures control?  Alternative is to use Java executors?

Answer (score 1):

What about [promises](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/async.html#promises)?

Something like:

```
def promises = items.collect{ item -> 
    task { 
        triggerWebService(item) 
    } 
}
def result = waitAll(promises)
```